# Calculate rate of return of a stock, if there is a buy transaction occurs during the middle of financial year

Tags: equities, investment

Currently, I'm implementing a feature of an open source project (https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/issues/7), which requires me to calculate the rate of return of a stock.

Let's take the following scenario.

> User purchased 1000 units stock with unit price 1 dollar at 1st
>   January 2013. He didn't perform any sell transaction & buy transaction
>   in between. At 31st December 2013, the stock price reached 2 dollar.

The rate of return of the stock for year 2013 is 100%

```
(Value of investment at 31st December 2013 - Cost of investment at 1st January 2013) / (Cost of investment at 1st January 2013) * 100%

(1000 * $2 - 1000 * $1) / (1000 * $1) * 100% = 100%
```

But, what if the user had purchased another **1000 units of same stock with unit price 1 dollar at 1st March 2013**. What should be the rate of return of the stock for year 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what [XIRR](http://www.jagoinvestor.com/2009/08/what-is-irr-and-xirr-and-how-to.html) does or can you read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179866/xirr-calculation).

Basically it tries to find an interest rate that works out to the same numbers.

I think Excel and Google Docs use the Newton approximation

http://www.mftransparency.org/calculating-interest-rates-using-newtons-method/

There's also a java implementation available on github called [jxirr](https://github.com/ept/jxirr).